# torch module not found in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, anaconda

I am trying to import torch in a jupyter notebook python file and getting this error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Also I have it installed in the created environment :

```
(pytorch_project) C:\Users\user>python
Python 3.7.15 (default, Nov 24 2022, 18:44:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>>
```

How can I make it work in the jupyter notebook also ?

Comment: In the notebook where you want to run it, make a new cell and run `%conda install -c pytorch pytorch`. Restart the kernel and now the import should work and not give you the module not found error. That magic command run from inside a notebook will insure the installation occurs in the environment backing the kernel underlying the notebook. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern `%conda install` and `%pip install` commands for use from inside notebooks.

Comment: I meant to add that the suggestion to do that is if you are already happy with your Jupyter installation otherwise and don't care about having additional installations of PyTorch. Otherwise, joe32140 's advice is the way to go. What I posted above is just meant as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you didn't install jupyter notebook in you conda env. Test it by

```bash
where jupyter
```

in you current env.

If the path doest not contain `pytorch_project`, you need to install jupyter for your current conda env:

```bash
pip install jupyter
```

Then, reactivate the env if needed.